# Whatsapp messages dissappearing

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, instant-messaging

On Samsung Galaxy A5 Whatsapp most of the chats are **dissappearing by itself**. My mother is using this phone and its backs-up to **Google Drive** on a daily basis. I checked and can confirm that the messages are indeed missing not archived.

This has happened a few times and except the last one I was able to recover the messages by reinstalling and then renaming the second to last back-up file in `WhatsApp/Database`folder to `msgstore.db.crypt12`. However, it seems that Google Drive back-ups have precedence over local back-ups and local back-ups are disregarded upon reinstall.

1. Is it possible somehow to recover these missing messages and have them displayed together with recent messages (judging by the size of the back-up the messages seem to be included)?
2. Are there apps or Windows programs capable of selecting a particular
   back-up and loading it?
3. What can be done to prevent this from
   happening again?